# Scala casting to function

Tags: scala, functional-programming

For some reason i have an abstract class with the method `def apply(some : Some) : Any`. One of the subclasses in particular returns a partially applied function like

```
 return twoArgumentFunction(_ : Int, 1)
```

but the signature of apply is Any. The question is how to cast this to a function of one argument?

```
def usingApply(){ var f = A.apply() ; f(4)}
```

i was expecting some asInstanceOf() or something like that

Comment: Can you add a bit more of your code for context?

Comment: Just saying: Returning `Any` and then using it by type casting is a serious design issue

Comment: @Ankur Yes, i am aware of that! I have many classes implementing the abstract class with apply(some) and only one needs the returning value. It is aweful , and has been bugging me all day but is my last resort

Comment: @Illiax - If you post a simplified version of the problem as a new question and ask *"how can I avoid using `Any` as the return type here?"* I bet someone will have a good suggestion for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're just confused about the syntax for `asInstanceOf`. You provide the target type in square brackets (not parentheses), like any other generic type argument:

```
def usingApply(){ var f = A.apply().asInstanceOf[Int=>Int] ; f(4)}
```

That would cast the result of apply to `Int=>Int`, which is the same as `Function1[Int,Int]`.

Comment: sorry! i misstyped () instead of [].
But the answer is just what i needed! Thanks!